# Error on GoogleMaps API while being generated

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I've finished my last project that uses GoogleMaps API v3 sucessfully.
But now, with no reasons the map is not being generated anymore.

The window with all map controls is opened correctly but the map
itself is not. It shown only a gray screen.

There is no errors on the script before calls google.maps function and
there is no errors after it too!

Can anyone try to help me with this issue?

Thx anyway.

Comment: Maybe you have reached the limit of the free API, try to host it in other IP and/or domain to see if it still works, If it does then you definitely have reached the limit.

Comment: thks for your comment @pacofvf, I think you're right.
we have 3 differents environments, one of then is a new virtual machine and I'm using it as development environment. The other two is our internal QA server and our costumer's QA server.
It works perfectly only in my new VM, that I use to develop and test.

Another question. Do you know what type of licence I need to our servers? This funcionality will work only in the intranet portal.

Comment: you need [Google maps api premier](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/maps.html) there are two kinds of licenses, one is for public web sites, starting at $50 USD for every 1000 page views, in the 25,000 page views per year range, or the private license with unlimited page views starting at $2500 USD for 10 users, I got those prices in Mexico, if your are in Brazil you are getting almost the same prices.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when I used GoogleMaps API in a Jquery UI Dialog, the map div would be gray. I corrected this problem by resizing the map when I opened the Dialog. I am also using the GMAP3 Jquery plugin.

Here is the resizing function:

```
function resizeMyMap() {
        var mymap = $('#map_canvas').gmap3({ action: 'get', name: 'map' });
        google.maps.event.trigger(mymap, "resize");
        $('.gmap3').gmap3({
            action: 'autofit'
        });
    }
```

If you do not use the GMAP3 Jquery plugin, you can try this to resize the map:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
```

Comment: Hey @Sashenka, tkx for your reply.

I'll try your suggestion too!!! I'll let u know if it works!

Cya